# How to wait for transaction to be mined in web3dart?

Tags: transactions, ethereum-wallet-dapp, pending-transactions

I'm bulding a Dapp. My Dapp interact with erc20 tokens and erc20 tokens must be approved first. But how i can wait for the approve txn to be mined and success before doing other txn like transfer...

- I'm using web3dart with flutter

Answer (score 0):

In [IERC20](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20-allowance-address-address-) there is a function called `allowance`. It’s signature: `allowance(address owner, address spender) → uint256`

Description:

> Sets amount as the allowance of spender over the caller’s tokens.

You can check this function to make sure approve worked

Comment: That's not what i meant. I want to know for example i have 2 txns: txn1 and txn2, txn1 must be completed and success before execute the 2nd txn. How can i wait for the txn1 to finish and execute txn2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flashbots https://github.com/flashbots/ethers-provider-flashbots-bundle
may help to solve the problem

Comment: This suggestion may not solve the original poster's problem, as it sounds like they would like to handle the case of users submitting transactions normally from their wallet.